# Best Way to Setup Solr (Ant vs Maven)?

Tags: java, maven, ant, solr

I have a project that's currently built with ant that pulls the latest trunk version of Solr in through git and then builds through ant. I'm pretty used to Maven and its system for dependencies at this point and find our old ant way of doing things pretty messy and hard to maintain. With that said, basically everywhere I seem to look online, people are building solr with Ant, and the few tutorials I found for doing things with Maven are all along the lines of [this one](http://uomesh.blogspot.com/2011/11/building-solr-as-maven-project.html), which doesn't seem to work.

So, to be clear, all I'm looking for here is a clean way to develop the project in Eclipse and to be able to deploy it. I'm sure someone must have done this before and must have a good answer. I'd be really interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got it working by throwing all dependencies into Maven, making my own repo for a pegged version of Solr 4.0-SNAPSHOT, copying the web.xml from it into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/, and running things through mvn jetty:run with salient variables passed in as arguments as:

```
mvn jetty:run -Dsolr.dataDir="./solr-data" -Dsolr.master-host="localhost" -Dsolr.solr.home="./solr-home"
```

This method is officially unsupported, but it means I no longer have to bother with ugly ant configs or holding all of Lucene and Solr in git repos attached to my project, so I could build from them. It also means changing/updating versions just requires a one line change in my pom.xml instead of digging through and switching a whole ton of extraneous configs. I'm pretty happy, and once I got a better feel for how Solr is supposed to work, reconfiguring the project really wasn't that bad.

Comment: Congrats then. You should probably accept your own answer then. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This answer is probably more a comment, but a comment is too small to expose it all.

I know nothing about Solr, but from a neutral point of view, I would say you have two options:

1. Mavenize Solr (looks like what is suggested by your article). Maybe you could post another question on what problems you encounter using their solution.
2. Invoke the original ant tasks using the maven-antrun-plugin. This would also probably require to attach the built jars (or if it only contains classes/resources, jar them first). You could decide to install them locally using maven-install-plugin or attach them with maven-build-helper-plugin.

In eclipse, there are plenty of tricks to access the built files. You could simply add the project as a dependency.

This second option should work, but I don't find it very clean

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Maven if you want, I know some of the Solr developers do. Have a look here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Maven. This isn't the most supported way though, and I can't help you with this since I never tried it.

I actually work with Solr + Ant and there's basically a task for everything: `ant test`, `ant dist` and so on. I agree that's a bit old fashioned, but it works. Lately the build has been improved a lot introducing Ivy as dependency management tool, in order to remove all jars from the source tree.

Let me know if you have some specific problems with ant, maybe I can help you more.